# How to create a nullable record in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

I create a `Inline table function` in SQL Server 2008 R2, and I realized some queries return any record. So I'd like when that happens, returns a record with all the empty columns.

By example:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
NULL   NULL   NULL
```

UPDATE: Here is the function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetWorksheetSummaryByObjective](@objectiveId [smallint], @testTemplateId [smallint])
RETURNS @resultTable TABLE (
    [AnsweredWorksheetId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [LastDate] [date] NULL,
    [BestScore] [smallint] NULL,
    [ShouldBeMakeUp] [tinyint] NOT NULL
)
AS 
BEGIN

    INSERT @resultTable
    SELECT TOP 1 B.Id AS AnsweredWorksheetId, A.Date, CONVERT(smallint, B.Score * 100),
        CASE
        WHEN B.Score >= 0.7 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END AS ShouldBeMakeUp
    FROM AnsweredTest AS A
    RIGHT JOIN AnsweredWorksheet AS B ON (A.Id = B.AnsweredTestId)
    WHERE B.ObjectiveId = @objectiveId AND A.ExamTemplateId = @testTemplateId
    ORDER BY B.Score DESC

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Did you mean to say "I realized some queries **don't** return any record."? (i.e rather than returning zero rows you want to return a single row with all columns `NULL`?) Please post the function.

Comment: you have to help us realize how do you realize that query return any record, you know :)

Comment: @MartinSmith sorry for my bad english, and you're right

Comment: The function you have posted is a multi statement TVF not an inline TVF. Inline TVFs have `RETURNS TABLE`, can't have any procedural logic and are usually more efficient than multi statement ones as they are inlined into the query and can be optimized in context.

Comment: Why do you want something like a row with all NULLs instead of no row? Perhaps you should use an outer join...

Comment: Or an `OUTER APPLY` depending on how you are using this function.

Answer (score 1):

The function you have posted is a **not** an inline TVF.

Given that the underlying query returns at most 1 row because of the `TOP 1` and `SELECT MAX()` without a `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` always returns a single row you could do this as an inline TVF however as below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Getworksheetsummarybyobjective](@objectiveId    [SMALLINT],
                                                       @testTemplateId [SMALLINT])
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT Max(AnsweredWorksheetId) AS AnsweredWorksheetId,
              Max([LastDate])          AS [LastDate],
              Max([BestScore])         AS [BestScore],
              Max(ShouldBeMakeUp)      AS ShouldBeMakeUp
       FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 B.Id                             AS AnsweredWorksheetId,
                            A.Date                           AS [LastDate],
                            CONVERT(SMALLINT, B.Score * 100) AS [BestScore],
                            CASE
                              WHEN B.Score >= 0.7 THEN 0
                              ELSE 1
                            END                              AS ShouldBeMakeUp
               FROM   AnsweredTest AS A
                      RIGHT JOIN AnsweredWorksheet AS B
                        ON ( A.Id = B.AnsweredTestId )
               WHERE  B.ObjectiveId = @objectiveId
                      AND A.ExamTemplateId = @testTemplateId
               ORDER  BY B.Score DESC) T)
```

Comment: @AndriyM - No. It is to get a single row if the subquery returns zero rows.

Comment: Yes, that's what I missed, thanks for explaining. An alternative could be to `SELECT T.* FROM (VALUES (NULL)) dummy (dummy) LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 ... ) T ON 1=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
declare @tbl table
(
  Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int
)

insert @tbl (Col1, Col2, Col3)
     select Col1, Col2, Col3 from SomeTable where blah = blah

if exists (select 1 from @tbl)
begin
    select Col1, Col2, Col3 from @tbl
end
else
begin
    select null Col1, null Col2, null Col3
end
```

Comment: `if ... else` is not allowed in an inline TVF

Comment: please replace `begin` in the `else` part

Answer (score 0):

Ok, skip my other answer - didn't realize how restrictive table functions were. I've got another thought - this one should work, but it means having to run the WHERE twice in the function, so double the resources to make the call:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SomeTest
    ( @i int ) 
RETURNS TABLE
as
RETURN 
    select Col1, Col2 from SomeTable
    where Whatever = Whatever

    union all

    select null Col1, null Col2
    where not exists (select 1 from SomeTable where Whatever = Whatever)
go
```

EDIT: Thought of another way to do this without the double-dipping:

```
create function dbo.SomeTest
    ( @i int )
returns table
as
return
select t.Col1, t.Col2 from 
(
    select Col1, Col2
    from SomeTable
    where Whatever = Whatever
) t
right join
(
    select 1 testcol
) x on c.Col1 is not null
go
```

This assumes that Col1 is a non-null column.